# Show actual progress from countdowntimer in ProgressBar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-progressbar

I have a layout that contains  a circular ProgressBar and a TextView showing a countdown.
How can I show the current progress of a timer in a progress bar? The progress bar should be full when first shown and empty when the timer is up.

```
    private fun setProgressBar(timeToShow: Int) {
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(
            timeToShow * ONE_SECOND_INTERVAL,
            ONE_SECOND_INTERVAL
        ) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                question_time.text = (millisUntilFinished / ONE_SECOND_INTERVAL).toString()
                //handleProgressBar
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
               hideLayout()
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/question_time_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progressbar"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_time"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/test_color_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="14" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#DDD" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="16"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the maximum of progress to the number from where count down begins.
e.g if the count down begins from 60.
you should set progressBar.setMax(60)

then also at each countdown set the value for progress bar
e.g progressBar.setValue(59) , then 58 , then 57....
the progressbar will work the way you want.